# Bash delete suffix if exists

Tags: bash

I will have a variable (let's call it `$name`) that could follow one of the following patterns;

```
foo
foo-green
foo-blue
foo-bar
foo-bar-green
foo-bar-blue
```

What's the lightest way in Bash to strip the `-green` or `-blue` suffix's if they exist, and leave the rest untouched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
name="${name%-green}"
name="${name%-blue}"
```

Comment: Or more generally `name=${name%-*}` which trims from the last dash to the end of the string.

Comment: @tripleee: Unfortunately that will also remove things such as "-bar".

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately.  I see now from the OP's question that they have some suffixes which they don't want to appear but others who come here might find the comment useful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `extglob` you can do this in a single step:

```
# utility function to strip green or blue from end of string
cstrip() { shopt -s extglob; echo "${1%-@(green|blue)}"; }

# use it as
cstrip 'foo-bar-blue'
foo-bar

cstrip 'foo-bar-green'
foo-bar

cstrip 'foo-blue'
foo

cstrip 'foo-bar'
foo-bar
```

Comment: You could put the `shopt` inside the function too and not have it affect globs in the rest of your script (though it gets a bit clunky).

Comment: Did you really mean `return`?

Comment: Sorry typo. It is fixed now.

Comment: @tripleee Shell options are global to the shell in which `shopt` is executed; putting `shopt` inside the function leaves the option set after the function exists, unless the body of the function is a subshell (`cstrip () ( ... )`).

Comment: @chepner I envisioned unsetting again at the end of the function, but it's clunky alright.

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
[[ $name =~ (.*)(-green|-blue) ]] && name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$name"
```

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that pattern handling in Bash was not implemented efficiently.  While most of the time the difference is entirely negligible and not the deciding factor between the two, I still wonder if regex matching will typically be quicker or slower than expansion with patterns for simple needs like that (short strings, simple matching), as my intuitive expectation would be "slower", but what I read is causing me to doubt that.